# Restricting OIDC for AzureAD (Entra) on a per-user basis

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, microsoft-entra-id

I have an external app that wants to implement single sign on of users by integrating with  Azure AD using OIDC, so that users may log in with their corporate Microsoft account into this external web app.

My question is: Is it possible to set up *per-user* policies to allow OIDC login, so that only a *subset* of users may log in to the external app using their AD account? For example by only letting users in a specific AD group authorize this external app?

Example:

- foo@somecompany.com and bar@somecompany.com are both members of EXT_APP_GROUP.
- The external app using the OpenID Connect Authorization Code Flow calls the OIDC connect URL to authorize users.
- john.doe@somecompany.com tries to login to the external app, and the call to AzureAD to authorize this user using OIDC fails due to this user not being a member of the EXT_APP_GROUP group in the AD.
- foo@somecompany.com and bar@somecompany.com are able to login to the external app using OIDC.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in OAuth you manage this with the following approach:

- Client redirects to authorization server (AS)
- AS runs a login method, eg by using an external identity provider (IDP)
- AS runs a custom action that inspects user attributes to decide whether to allow a specific user access

An IDP will allow any valid user to authenticate. Whether they are granted access is an authorization question.

I don't think Azure AD supports running the above type of custom action. You may be able to use an [authentication methods policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/how-to-authentication-methods-manage) to restrict access to members of a particular group though.

If your AS does not support denying access, you can handle the authorization failure after login in your app. Eg ensure that APIs deny access based on group membership.